# sending commands to a terminal from another one

Tags: unix, process, system, stdin, pipe

Let suppose you have a terminal (T1) open with 6350 pid.

Type :

```
echo "ls\n" > /proc/6350/fd/0 (writen in another terminal (T2)).
```

This writes ls and the line jump in T1 but does not execute it ? Why ?

I also tried using

```
cat|bash with echo "ls\n" > /proc/catPID/fd/0
```

but it is still not executed.

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Edited :

One possible trick :

```
mkfifo toto

$bash < toto

$echo "ls" > toto
```

Comment: without "\n"? `echo "ls" > /proc/6350/fd/0`

Answer (score 1):

First, if you want `echo` to  intpret the `\n` as newline you have to call it with `-e`.

Secondly, what you  want (hijack a terminal) is not (easy) doable, see [unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17838/how-can-i-switch-between-ttys-without-using-screen). I would use `screen` on both sessions (one with the -x option).

Comment: `echo` without option `-n` appends a `\n` to the arg.

Comment: @rvlander: The tip with the echo was just how to output the \n in case you want to output it (as MirkoBanchi already mentioned it isnt necessary as echo already outputs on its own). Your problem is that your want to "hijack" the pts, which is not doable.